# How to create a Hello World SWT application in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am trying to follow instructions in Eclipse to create my first Hello World SWT application. I have problems on the first step. In the instructions the following is written:

> Open your Web browser to
>   http://eclipse.org/downloads/,
>   navigate to the Eclipse Platform
>   project section, select the latest
>   release build, and find the SWT Binary
>   and Source download.

Well I am smart enough to "open my Web browser to http://eclipse.org/downloads/". This I can do. But I am not smart enough to "navigate to the Eclipse Platform project section, select the latest release build, and find the SWT Binary and Source download".

Can anybody help me to find this "Eclipse Platform project section"? Should I click on "Projects"? If it is the case, what should I click next?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go here, http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-2.1-200303272130/index.php and scroll all the way to the bottom to see *SWT Binary and Source*

Which may be a bit outdated, so go to http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ and under Development section, select your operating system.

Comment: Thank you. I visited the page you gave and clicked "Linux". Then I have selected a mirror and downloaded a swt-3.5.1-gtk-linux-x86.zip file. But now I do not know what to do because in the eclipse instructions it is written that "Save the file to your disk; you do not need to extract the archive". And I have an archive. Should I not to extract the archive?

Comment: Can eclipse read from archive? How eclipse know where the archive is located and what is the name of the file.

Comment: If the instructions are telling you not to, then don't and continue on. Where are you getting these instructions from?

Comment: In the "start page" of eclipse I clicked "Create a Hello World SWT application" and then I got the instructions (in the eclipse) how to do it.

Comment: Well, if the instructions are telling you not to extract it, then don't, continue on with the instructions and all should be well.

Answer (score 1):

From http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/samples/org.eclipse.swt.examples/doc-html/swt_manual_setup.html :

Adding SWT to your workspace

1. Download SWT for standalone applications. A standalone version of SWT is available on the same download page as the Eclipse SDK. Look for the section titled SWT Binary and Source. Do not extract the archive file, just save it to disk.
2. Select Import... from the File menu.
3. Select Existing Projects into Workspace and click on the Next button.
4. Select Select archive file: and use the Browse button to locate the SWT standalone archive you have previously downloaded.
5. Click on the Finish button.

This worked for me under Ubuntu on my netbook; I've been fighting for a few days to configure Eclipse and I'm getting closer to done.